SOAP Get list of Operation
I want to get list of operation from below SOAP service,
    URL wsdlURL = new URL("https://xyz/v41.2?wsdl");
    
    // Namespace and service name
    QName serviceName = new QName("urn:com.wd/bsvc/Int", "IntService");
    
    // Create a service instance
    Service service = Service.create(wsdlURL, serviceName);

How to get list of Operation?
